# Understanding Python for-loops at a beginner level

Tags: python, matlab, for-loop, vector, indexing

I realize many of these questions have been asked before, but I cannot seem to find the answers for myself.

I'm fairly fluent in Matlab but I cannot understand these Python for-loops. I've written this small script in Matlab and I want to do the same in Python.

**Matlab**

```
h = 2;
w = pi / 2;
t = 0:.01:4;
smP = [1 2]';
r = [h * cos(w * t') 2 * h * sin(w * t')]';
A = zeros(2,2,length(t));
rP = zeros(2,length(t));
for i = 1:length(t)
    A(:,:,i) = [cos(w * t(i)) -sin(w * t(i)); sin(w * t(i)) cos(w * t(i))];
    rP(:,i) = r(:,i) + A(:,:,i) * smP;
end
plot(rP(1,:),rP(2,:))
```

I can't get the `rP(:,i)`-style indexing to work in Python. I've tried a few things.

**Attempt 1**

```
r = np.matrix([h * np.cos(w * t), 2 * h * np.sin(w * t)])
A = np.array([[np.cos(w * t), -np.sin(w * t)], [np.sin(w * t), np.cos(w * t)]])

rP = []
for i in range(len(t)):
    instant = r[:,i] + A[:,:,i] @ smP
    rP.append(instant)
```

**Attempt 2**

```
rP = np.zeros([2,len(t)])
for i in range(len(t)):
    rP[:][i] = r[:,i] + A[:,:,i] @ smP
```

This gives me a 400-list (with my current size of t) that contains a 2x1 vector at every index. This I can't seem to plot and it is just a bad way to save my data. I Obviously want a 2xlength(t) matrix where every column is the vector rP at discrete time steps (just like the Matlab code).

How can I to accomplish this simple thing in Python?

Comment: Don’t use `np.matrix`, I understand they are deprecated. Just use `np.array` for everything. Then replace MATLAB’s round indexing braces with Python’s square ones.

Comment: And replace one-based indices with zero-based ones where applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following solution:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from numpy import sin, cos, hstack, vstack

h = 2
w = np.pi / 2
t = np.arange(0, 4+0.01, 0.01) # t = 0:.01:4;
smP = np.array((1, 2)) # smP = [1 2]';
r = vstack((h * cos(w * t), 2 * h * sin(w * t))) #r = [h * cos(w * t') 2 * h * sin(w * t')]';
A = np.zeros((2, 2, len(t))) #A = zeros(2,2,length(t));
rP = np.zeros((2, len(t))) #rP = zeros(2,length(t));

for i in range(len(t)):  #for i = 1:length(t)
    A[:,:,i] = vstack((hstack((cos(w * t[i]), -sin(w * t[i]))), hstack((sin(w * t[i]), cos(w * t[i]))))) #    A(:,:,i) = [cos(w * t(i)) -sin(w * t(i)); sin(w * t(i)) cos(w * t(i))];
    rP[:,i] = r[:,i] + A[:,:,i].dot(smP.T)  #    rP(:,i) = r(:,i) + A(:,:,i) * smP;

plt.plot(rP[0,:], rP[1,:])  #plot(rP(1,:),rP(2,:))
plt.show(block=True)
```

Please note that my Python level is not that grate...